# Why isn't regexpwndtitle picking up multi-line value shown in object spy in UFT?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Here's what is happening:

1. Application (C++) is displaying a popup message
2. Object Spy shows the regexpwndtitle property of the message text as having a value of "multi-line value"
3. When the property/values are copied into the clipboard and then viewed,
   the regexpwndtitle value shows regexpwndtitle:= Special:  This
   allows you to save the value.\r\n, which is the second line in the list!

I've tried setting the regexpwndtitle to a regular expression that should match the text in the first line of the message (.*subset of first line of popup message.*), to no avail.

Anyone with similar difficulties that has cracked this?

Thanks

Comment: Please do a GetROProperty (TO,"regexpwndtitle") on TO, and hex-dump the result. You will exactly see what is contained, which would be a first step to developing a regex that matches that title.

Comment: Did u try using the regular expression elevator ? this page should give u more idea http://community.hpe.com/t5/All-About-the-Apps/Regular-Expressions-in-UFT/ba-p/6197241#.VsY1xflVhBc

Comment: Thanks Prageeth.  I think you meant evaluator, yes?

Comment: I will try the GetROProperty now.  Thanks!